# Android browser php cookies

Tags: php, android

I am unable to manipulate cookies via php on the vanilla android browser. (ver 2.3.4)

The browser options are set to accept cookies, and some websites do allow me to log in normally (though not all).

I have made a really simple test script to try and see if cookies are set at all:

```
setcookie("TestCookie", "cookievalue", time()+3600);
```

and on the next page

```
echo $_COOKIE["TestCookie"];
```

On my desktop browser or on firefox mobile this displays the word "cookievalue" but on the android browser it's blank. This issue also won't let me store anything in a session cookie since that won't persist.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you testing against a domain name or IP adresses / and or (not) using a port?

Comment: I'm testing with a domain name. On the php side i've tried specifying the domain of the cookie, and on the client side I've tried it with and without a subdomain.

Comment: More investigation on my friend's phone leads me to believe this may be something with our data provider. His totally different phone and browser version has this problem on websites like phpbb.com yet the firefox browser doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Check as well with a site that does not run under PHP and uses cookies as well.

Comment: Ok I tried logging into a site done in .net and it persists the session state with cookies as it should. I'm now totally confused, is this php, a proxy issue from my provider, or both. I've found another site done in php (a vbulletin forum) where the login works but I think they're using javascript to set a cookie there. :|

Comment: Only rely on facts. For example gather all hard data, like the browser vendor, the headers that get passed (or not) etc.. You need to debug this to find out more, time is over for making any assumptions and guesses. Just the hard facts. It's time, and this can take times (up to month), but better start early.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After examining things closely and trying all options I've discovered that this is indeed a problem with how the stock browser is handling cookies when android is configured to use a port and proxy in the APN settings. I suspect that it has problems associating cookies with their domains under certain conditions when these settings are on. (cookies were being set, but lost as soon as a page redirect or link was clicked).

My provider had these in there by default. Removing them so that the fields are blank has solved this problem.

Anyone else having this issue, I suggest going into your wireless networks options, finding the access point names setting, selecting the active APN and clearing the port and proxy fields if they are filled in. (write them down first in case this doesn't work for you)

After you do this you'll have to re-register on your network by searching for available networks and selecting it again.

Answer (score 0):

That code will not work. Cookie data set with `setcookie` does not become available until the next page request.

Comment: First of all, it does if you just refresh the page. Secondly you've ignored my question. This affects across pages, as well as session state.

Comment: If you're having this issue on other sites that aren't made by you, it's not a PHP problem, it's a problem with your phone. Android and PHP work just fine with cookies.

Comment: I have tested this as well on another phone owned by a friend and found the same issue. He was running 2.3.3. I would prefer a knowledgeable answer as to why this might happen.

Comment: The code you've excerpted works fine on the three Android test devices available to me. The knowledgeable answer is "this shouldn't happen, look into other causes".